# Plotting in RMarkdown

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

I want to plot boxplots showing the average test scores by Parents' education and jobs. My data includes variables: average, Medu, Fedu, Mjob, Fjob and other variables. I'm going to plot 2 separate plots for Parents' education and Parents' jobs.

I have successfully written and knitted the plot showing average scores ~ parents' jobs with the following code lines:

```
family %>%
    select(Mjob, Fjob, average)%>%
    gather(key=Parent, value=job, -average) %>%
    ggplot(aes(job, average, fill=Parent))+
    geom_boxplot(varwidth=T, alpha=0.2)+
    xlab("Parents' jobs")+
    scale_fill_discrete(labels=c("Father","Mother"))
```

[image: Job plot]

But when I do the same thing with Parents' education plot using the following code, the knitted plot is oddly different

```
family %>%
    select(Medu, Fedu, average) %>%
    gather(key=Parent, value=education, -average) %>%
    ggplot(aes(education, average, fill=Parent))+
    geom_boxplot(varwidth=T, alpha=0.2)+
    xlab("Parents' education")+
    scale_fill_discrete(labels=c("Father","Mother"))
```

[image: Education plot]

However, when I re-check and run the code in RMarkdown, it shows the correct plot (see below), meaning that my code isn't wrong. But again, the plot shown in html is different What is the problem here? Appreciate your help!

[image: correct plot]

Comment: I wonder if this is due to your environment.  Whenever I see different things happening in the console vs. in a Markdown document, it makes me think this is the issue.  The way to think about it is that the Markdown document exists in a completely separate environment vs. your local one (where the console normally is running).  This is why you have to have `library()` calls in the Markdown document even if you have the package loaded in your local environment.  What happens if you clear your local environment, then run each code chunk *in the console*?  Does the result match the Markdown doc?

Comment: I have realized my problem, it should be factor(education) in order for the knit to run correctly. And yes, I think it's the markdown environment that causes this disparity in my graphs. Thank for your sharing!